# ajax speed - boiling down multiple ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search filter on my site whereby when a user unchecks a box, an ajax call is posted to the server, returning new, narrowed down search results.

now, however, the user has the ability to uncheck about 20 boxes at the same time, which forces me to make 20 different ajax calls -- this is very slow

any ideas on how to pass the 20 different ajax calls into one so as to speed up things?

here is my js:

```
// to allow us to process the "only" buttons, which don't register the click event we're looking for
        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {

            // remove the original, unfiltered results
            $('#original_results').css("display", "none");

            // which filter section does the filter belong to
            var filter_section = $(this).attr('name');

            // should it be filtered out or left in
            var remove = $(this).prop('checked');

            // if needs to be filtered
            if (!remove)
            {
                // add it to our filter list for the specified section
                filters[filter_section].push(this.value);
            }
            else
            {
                // take it off the list for the specified section
                var index = filters[filter_section].indexOf(this.value);
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    filters[filter_section].splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
            doAjax();
        });

    // ajax function

        function doAjax() {
            // get slider values
            var ranges = $('#pay_range').slider('values');
            // define data to post
            var data = {
                min: ranges[0],
                max: ranges[1],
                filters: filters,
                criteria: criteria
            };
            // post data



            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/results/search_filter',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#search_results').html('Updating your query');
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#search_results').html(response);
                },
                dataType: "html"

            });


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you want your AJAX call to only happen once per action, even if the action includes changing multiple checkboxes.

I've achieved this using javascript's `setTimeout()` to "buffer" events. When a checkbox is changed, a short timeout is set which will fire the AJAX. If another checkbox is changed within that time period, the timeout will be re-set (instead of firing the AJAX twice). The AJAX only fires once at the end of the timeout.

```
// initialize timer variable
var ajaxtimer;    

// function to run AJAX
function runajax() {
    alert('ajax');
}

// clicking a checkbox sets all checkboxes to the same state
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked).change();
});

// fires on checkbox change, sets short timeout
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
    clearTimeout(ajaxtimer);
    ajaxtimer = setTimeout(runajax, 50);
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/GR8zu/1/)

### Edit:

I saw the link you posted and made the following adjustments:

I defined this variable at the top of the file:

```
var ajaxtimer;
```

On line 156 of results.js, I changed:

```
doAjax();
```

to

```
clearTimeout(ajaxtimer);
ajaxtimer=setTimeout(doAjax,50);
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdsKR/). The layout is butchered, but you can see that clicking an "only" link results in only one ajax call, rather than one call for every checkbox that was changed.

Comment: hmmm, interesting idea. i've tried implementing it without success. you can see exactly what I'm trying to do here: http://laoshilist.com/results/display/ if you try and press "only" on any of the filter elements -- in devtools, you'll see just how many post requests are made and how slow it is

Comment: What went wrong with your implementation? I added an example based on your code, above.

Comment: the problem is just that it's still extremely slow and even causes the pages to be unresponsive